# Send data over TCP/IP with sockets and serialize data

Tags: c++, sockets

i have to send via TCP/IP with sockets a string formatted as CHARINT,INT where CHAR is a character and INT are numbers. Which is the best way to send them and receive them? And how could i split that string when I receive it to have again the two integers?

Comment: Your end goal will dictate the best option. For instance, you could use Boost ASIO for portability concerns, or you could use Google Protocol Buffers for binary compatibility between machines, but all of these are pretty silly requirements if you're only working on a homework assignment or a small thing for you to tinker with. Please elaborate.

Comment: I would also suggest using `Google Protocol Buffers` it works for C++, Python and Java.

Comment: it sounds to me like you're in waaay over your head if you can't understand the alignment issues Eugene spoke of, you don't think it important for resolving this issue to mention what system you are sending on as well as what system you are receiving on, and you can't take the time to list your end goal. My suggestion is to do some reading before you code if you are indeed at this point. I/O is never an easy implementation, even with all of the wonderful libraries we have available to us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do what you need, and the choice depends on how extensible you need to the solution to be. If all you need is two integers, then you can send them by putting them to array  "int arr[2];" and use send(arr, 2*sizeof(int)) call to send the data. When receiving the data you do the opposite.

Quite simple but easy to implement method to serialize small amounts of data is to convert numbers to text (using itoa()) and send a coma-separated list of values. On the other side you parse the string by simply splitting it using coma as a separator and then using atoi() to convert values back to ints.

However, for anything more complex you need more flexible scheme. Search for "serialization" on this site for various options. Any generic scheme would require a parser and it makes sense to not reinvent the wheel. ASN.1 is a universal binary protocol for serialization, extensively used in communications industry.

Comment: yes i must send only 1 character followed by and integer, a comma and another integer

Comment: @Stefano if you can live with aligned data, declare a struct with fields that you have, populate it and pass it to send() method. Read right into the struct on the receiver side.

Comment: could you post an example of how should i send a receive the struct?

Comment: The same as with array I described in the answer. It would be something like "struct msg_str { char c1; int i1; char commaChar; int i2; }; ... msg_str msg; ... send(socket, msg, sizeof(msg));"

Comment: but how can i use recv to receive the struct data?

Comment: @Stefano the same way: "recv(socket, msg, sizeof(msg));"  . Note, that this approach will work only in simpliest case where the sender and recipient work on machines with the same processor architecture (eg. both are x86 or both are x64) and the code is compiled using the similar compiler with the same structure alignment. As I said above, this is very simple and straightfoward method to send the data. Converting it to string and back might be more flexible approach (and not much harder).

Comment: If the amount of data to be sent is small, using a string representation may well be best.  This not only solves big vs. little endian and related numeric format issues, it means that what goes over the network is human readable, which is a huge convenience in debugging.  You can for example use netcat as a substitute for either end of the connection and interact with the other end manually, as if you were the expected program.

Comment: thw application won't work on the same machine hardware so I think that as you said structures are not the way. I only need to send two integers separated by comma over the network so i think that a string is ok but i don't know how could i convert the int to char* so that I can pass it to the send function

Comment: @Stefano did you check docs for itoa() and atoi() functions that I mentioned?